# Giving isset values to a string

Tags: php

I am trying to make it so that my `$url` string will display the content from the url when `example.com/?url=MyExample.com` is set.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen("s.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why complicate it so much?

```
if(isset($_GET["url"]))                   //  you can add check to validate url
$content=file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
```

Now you can display it like

```
echo $content;
```

Or save in your file like

```
file_put_contents("s.txt",$content);  // you can check whether this failed
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you for answering my noob riddled question!